# Border shadow in Circle Android

Tags: android

[image]

Can anyone suggest that how to give shadow on border of circle like above image.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:innerRadius="0dp"
android:shape="ring"
android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
android:useLevel="false" >
<solid android:color="#33FFFFFF" />

<stroke
    android:width="5dp"
    android:color="@android:color/white" /></shape>
```

But I am not able to create shadow like above Image.

Please Help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- "background shadow" -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="circle" >
        <solid android:color="#000000" />

        <corners android:radius="15dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- background color -->
<item
    android:bottom="3px"
    android:left="3px"
    android:right="3px"
    android:top="3px">
    <shape android:shape="circle" >
        <solid android:color="#cc2b2b" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- over left shadow -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="circle" >
        <gradient
            android:angle="180"
            android:centerColor="#00FF0000"
            android:centerX="0.9"
            android:endColor="#99000000"
            android:startColor="#00FF0000" />

    </shape>
</item>
<!-- over right shadow -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="circle" >
        <gradient
            android:angle="360"
            android:centerColor="#00FF0000"
            android:centerX="0.9"
            android:endColor="#99000000"
            android:startColor="#00FF0000" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- over top shadow -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="circle" >
        <gradient
            android:angle="-90"
            android:centerColor="#00FF0000"
            android:centerY="0.9"
            android:endColor="#00FF0000"
            android:startColor="#99000000"
            android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- over bottom shadow -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="circle" >
        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:centerColor="#00FF0000"
            android:centerY="0.9"
            android:endColor="#00FF0000"
            android:startColor="#99000000"
            android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Or something like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/shadow"
    android:id="@id/shadow"
    android:top="dimension"
    android:right="dimension"
    android:bottom="dimension"
    android:left="dimension" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/hh"
    android:id="@id/ring"
    android:top="dimension"
    android:right="dimension"
    android:bottom="dimension"
    android:left="dimension" />
</layer-list>
```

Where shadow is something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="circle">
<gradient
  android:centerColor="@android:color/darker_gray" 
  android:endColor="@android:color/darker_gray" 
  android:startColor="@android:color/darker_gray"  />
<size  android:height="140dp"
    android:width="120dp" />
</shape>
```